# Facebook api associate multiple PSID to a label

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, broadcast

I have a problem with Targeting Broadcast Messages. 
From this link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages/target-broadcasts#associate_label, I know that "To associate a label to a specific PSID, send a POST request to the //label endpoint" .

It's fine but can I associate multiple PSID to the label in a single request ? I have too many PSID to associate and I don't want to make that much API call.
Thanks

Comment: It would usually be mentioned in the docs, if that was possible. I mean you can try to provide a comma-separated list or a JSON-like array for the parameter … but I rather doubt it will work. You should be able to send batch requests for this though, to at least save on HTTP requests, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

Comment: I tried "id1,id2", "id1;id2", [id1, id2] but no luck. Sometime it show no error but only add 1 id, not all

Comment: I feel your pain. I think they should allow for an array of PSID's when making the associate request; it does not make sense that we should send multiple batched requests if the amount of PSID's to be associated is large. In my case, I'm associating hundreds at a time.